# Логическое ударение

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Прочитав предложение "К сожалению, лучшие часто уходят слишком рано", куда читатель с большей вероятностью поставит логическое ударение: на "часто" (то есть автору жаль, что событие "лучшие уходят слишком рано" происходит часто) или на "рано"?

Comment: Разве выбор у читателя ограничен?

Answer (score 2):

1) **Вариант без логических ударений:**

**К сожалению, лУчшие // часто уходят слишком рАно.**

В этом случае предложение состоит из двух фраз, и тоническое ударение (повышение или понижение голоса) естественным образом делается в конце каждой фразы. Но это не логическое ударение.

2) **При логическом ударении** тоническое ударение смещается на другое слово (одновременно делается усиление ударного слога). В данном варианте смещение возможно только на слово ***часто,*** и это единственный вариант для логического выделения в этом предложении:

**К сожалению, лУчшие // чАсто уходят слишком рано.**

Comment: При первом прочтении не могу понять, почему логическое ударение не может быть на ***рано***.

Comment: Потому что автора беспокоит именно частота события, а не само событие. Взгляните на предложение: « К сожалению, я часто проигрываю.» Если бы меня беспокоили какие-либо проигрыши, то я бы сказал: К сожалению, в моей жизни случаются проигрыши.» Автора подобного предложения не устраивает частота проигрышей, а не то, что они вообще происходят.

Answer (score 2):

**С большей вероятностью** читатель поставит логическое ударение на ЧАСТО. Но именно **с большей**, а не стопроцентной.

Много раз прочитав предложение из вопроса, убедился, что это самое ударение можно сместить и на РАНО. Если убрать частотность и написать: ***К сожалению, лучшие уходят слишком рАно*** – это не будет соответствовать действительности. Поэтому необходимо добавить ЧАСТО, но не делать на нем логического ударения. Я, например, легко могу себе представить и воспроизвести такое прочтение (жаль, что здесь нет голосовой передачи).

Логическим ударением можно выделить даже УХОДЯТ, с меньшей, но всё же **вероятностью**.

Comment: Мое понимание темы отчасти изменилось, да и времени уже прошло много. Сейчас я считаю, что ударением можно выделить любое слово по желанию говорящего,  но какие есть  для этого возможности – вот в чем вопрос. В принципе мы можем без особых проблем переносить тоническое ударение с конца фразы на другие слова, и тогда они будут логически выделены,  причем усиления голоса для этого не потребуется. А вот поставить логическое ударение на конец фразы можно  только силовым способом –  соответственно, сделать это сложнее.

Comment: Поэтому такая фонетическая позиция неудобна для  логического подчеркивания.  Читающий такой текст вряд ли это сделает.

Comment: Да, прошло почти 4 года, и я знал, что вы напишете то, что написали. Пусть всё это останется в истории. Спасибо за плюс!

Comment: И откуда вы всё знаете? :)

Comment: Исходя из ваших "современных" взглядов.

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить несколько слов про «современные» взгляды . В первом ответе было предложено частное решение для конкретного лексического состава предложения (поэтому названо слово часто),  но интереснее и правильнее решать задачу в общем виде с учетом фонетических позиций слов. Так мы преодолеваем ограниченность в наших суждениях, и сейчас я  бы уже не стала говорить про «единственный вариант» .  Как правило, такие категоричные высказывания  далеко не всегда соответствуют истине, поэтому их лучше вообще не использовать.  В любом случае меня радует, что вы так  хорошо разобрались в теме.

Comment: Пожалуй, еще одно важное дополнение: в  этой теме надо учитывать инверсию дополнения относительно сказуемого (часто уходят), ведь нормальной считается его постпозиция. И вот без такой инверсии  выделить дополнение логическим ударением было бы  сложно.

Comment: Мне нравится ваш последний ответ (о слове «бывает»), всё очень четко и красиво оформлено. Кроме того, мне хотелось поблагодарить вам за участие в интонационном анализе. Мне показалась очень интересной ваша оценка  простого предложения в той части, что ударение в большей степени падает на конец заключительной фразы. Это действительно верно и мною раньше упускалось. Также я думаю, что ударение вообще связано с длительностью пауз: перед произносительной паузой оно проявляется в меньшей степени, чем перед паузой увеличенной и подчеркнутой.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения ударения, нужно отчетливо понимать тот смысл, который автор пытается донести. Вряд ли автора волновало, если бы лучшие уходили слишком рано не часто, а редко. Ну случаются плохие вещи: лучшие иногда уходят рано. Автора волнует то, что это происходит часто. Ударение падает на слово «часто».

Comment: Мой ответ неправильно изменили. Ну случаются плохие вещи, лучшие иногда уходят рано. = Ну случаются плохие вещи, ну уходят иногда лучшие рано. Я здесь не раскрывал эти плохие вещи. Это важное для смысла изменение.

Comment: Спасибо, что подняли этот вопрос!